# git clone from a server (using ssh)

Tags: git, ssh

My friend created a server and I tried to get the repository on local machine using this command:

```
git clone ssh://git@abc.com:10022/aaa/bbb.git
```

However, I get this error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and then he told me to login the git and give me: `user name`, `email` and `password`.

How can I login the git? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you added a SSH key to your gitlab account? Do you have permissions on the project? It's hard to just guess whats wrong! Otherwise just ask your friend?

Comment: @0stone0 it may not be a gitlab server. It’s quite possible to set up an independent standalone git server. OP, have either of you read [this section](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)? It’s considered “better” for you each to have an account that allows you to clone from the server.

Comment: The problem is that he forgot to add my public key to the server. The problem is now fixed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clone anything from git, you have to register on github/gitlab (depending where your friend has his git repo), then generate ssh key on your laptop/computer, like described here: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent.
Add public ssh key into your account on github/gitlab (depending where your friend has his git repo). And as a last step - to configure your git on laptop/computer:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Here is more information: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

Comment: what if my ssh key deleted ?

Comment: @DevangHingu you can generate a new ssh key and add a new one into github/gitlab, also remove the old one. Also if you have multiple laptops, you can have multiple ssh keys.